# Unsetting a variable after foreach

Tags: php

Is it a good practice to unset the variable after foreach?

heres a sample code:

```
foreach ($totalwins as $key => $value) {
//code here
}

unset($key);
```

Comment: PHP will automatically clean itself up.  I think it is better practice to not re-use variable names unless they are actually related.

Comment: when i try to use the $key variable the last value is stored in there.

Comment: It won't hurt, as it'll free up the memory ... however in most cases this is an over optimization that isn't required.

Comment: @frustratedprogrammer, yes that is to be expected.  Nothing in a foreach loop unsets, it just resets on each iteration.  But like I said, you shouldn't use `$key` again in that specific scope to avoid debugging hassles.

Comment: What is worse, it will cluster the code and make it harder to read. Code readability is the number one thing in most high-level tasks (that is, about 99% of what PHP is used for).

Answer (score 1):

Unless the object is taking up a significant amount of memory it makes practically no difference whether or not you unset it unless it's necessary for it to be unset, in which case I'd recommend rethinking that specific part of your process because I can't see a valid reason for it to be necessary let alone mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Most conventions would determine that future `foreach` loops define their own first-use of the $key. It comes down comfort with your code. As Devon said in the comments if you are really worried about it you could use distinct variable names, but this is not always possible.